# How to implement Open-close principle in the below mentioned situation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am aware of the Open close principle as a part of the SOLID object oriented design patterns. I have a situation where in I have an existing Employee POJO class with 10 fields ,its getter and setter methods, overriden equals and hashcode method. I have a new requirement to add 5 more fields to this old Employee class. Just wanted to know an opinion over this about how to proceed with such a situation? The simple way is to add the new 5 fields to the existing employee class and add it is getters and setters and thus implement the extended functionality. However the open close principle says that you should not touch the existing code and try create a new one by extending the existing one without changing the existing code.

Can somebody please guide me, how to go about it?

Comment: Just FYI in future, regarding _"Just wanted to know an opinion over this"_, please note that questions seeking opinions are explicitly off topic on Stack Overflow, and such questions are usually closed. In this specific case the answer to your question was not opinion based at all so it didn't matter, but avoid seeking opinions in a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) says that the class is *closed* for modification and open for extension. So you should add those extra fields to a subclass (i.e. extend the base class).

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking at the wikipedia page of Open-closed principle, I found these two quotes from Bertrand Meyer:

> A module will be said to be open if it is still available for extension. For example, it should be possible to add fields to the data structures it contains, or new elements to the set of functions it performs.
>
> A module will be said to be closed if [it] is available for use by other modules. This assumes that the module has been given a well-defined, stable description (the interface in the sense of information hiding).

Using these rules, then the answer to your question is whether or not the Employee class is already in use in production. If the Employee class is already being used by other classes in production, then it is considered "closed" and not available for modification. If the Employee class is not being used by any other classes in production, it is considered "open" and can be modified.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)

Comment: So does it mean that if the Employee class is already in production environment then we should create a new class and extend the Employee class and use the new class? And if it is not in production yet then we can just go and add those fields in the same employee class?

Comment: yes. although if your class is being used in a huge internal codebase, then you can probably consider it in production.